# Binding an XceedData Column EditTemplate to different property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xceed-datagrid

I have an Xceed DataGrid with an `EditTemplate` defined for the grid.

The grid shows a listing of items bound to a collection with about 6 columns and the `EditTemplate` is a `TextBox` control for entering a quantity.  I want the `IsReadOnly` property to be bound to a different property so that the item has a serial number, `IsReadOnly` will be set to true so the user cannot enter a value.  I want to bind to the `SerialNum` property within the same collection and pass it to a converter to return the true/false value.  I've got the converter written; however, I'm having issues binding to the property to pass to the converter.

My `DataGridCollectionViewSource` is simple enough:

```
<xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="transferItems" Source="{Binding TransferItems}" />
```

`TransferItems` is set in my ViewModel and all of the columns get properly bound.

For all of my generic display columns, they are being properly displayed via:

```
<xcdg:Column Title="Serial No." AllowSort="False" FieldName="SerialNum" />
```

My issue is in defining the `xcgd:CellEditor` template and I'm pretty sure my issue is around the `RelativeSource`.  I've tried many different combinations trying to get the `TransferItems.SerialNum` property from my ViewModel, but no combination is working.

This is what I currently have:

```
<xcdg:Column Title="Xfer Qty Good" TextWrapping="Wrap" ReadOnly="False" Width="50" AllowGroup="False" AllowSort="False" FieldName="TransferQtyGood">
    <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
        <xcdg:CellEditor>
            <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox x:Name="QtyGood" Margin="2,2,2,2" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}" IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource}}, Path=DataContext.TransferItems.SerialNum, Converter={StaticResource serialToEnabledConverter}}"
                     />
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
        </xcdg:CellEditor>
    </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
</xcdg:Column>
```

Which gives the runtime error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionViewSource', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.TransferItems.SerialNum; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name='QtyGood'); target property is 'IsReadOnly' (type 'Boolean')
```

I understand what the error is telling me, but I'm just getting the proper `RelativeSource` path.  I've read some of the helpful posts here on the enumerations for `RelativeSource` and still am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is having this issue, I was able to finally get the binding working in this manner.  The key is defining the correct RelativeSource path:

```
<TextBox x:Name="QtyGood" Margin="2,2,2,2" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     Text="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}" GotFocus="Qty_GotFocus" LostFocus="Qty_LostFocus"
                                     IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}, Path=DataContext.SerialNum, Converter={StaticResource serialToEnabledConverter}}"
                                     />
```